# How to use component.get() in Aura Controller for Boolean value in Component

Tags: aura, aura-attribute

I have a  boolean attribute in component

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="isOpptyExists" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

**Controller**

```
var isOpptyExists = component.get("c.isOpptyExists");
```

alert(isOpptyExists) -- But I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have to use the 'v' and not the 'c' object here.

```
var isOpptyExists = component.get("v.isOpptyExists");
```